# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions for non api call updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to manage a single state without any `a sync` actions but facing this error.
this is my `store.js`:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./../reducers";

const initialState = { todolist: [] };
export const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
```

this is my `action.js`:

```
export const setTodolist = listitem => {
    ({ type: "SET_TODOLIST", todolist: listitem })
};
```

this is my reducer.js:

```
export default (state, action) => {
    console.log(state , "reducer")
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_TODOLIST":
            return {
                ...state,
                todolist: [...state,  action.todolist]
            };
      default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

and finally this is my component:

```
import { store } from "./../redux/store";
import { setTodolist } from '../redux/actions';

export default class Mylist extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <input    placeholder="username" 
                    name="inputval" />
          <button className="mt-4" color="success" onClick={dispatchBtnAction} >Add Todo</button>   
      ) 
  }
}
function dispatchBtnAction(e) {
    const val = document.getElementsByName("inputval").value;
    store.dispatch(setTodolist({val}))
}
```

do you have any idea what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your action is incorrect. With your current syntax the object specified is just a block of code which isn't returned. You should either write it like

```
export const setTodolist = listitem => (
    { type: "SET_TODOLIST", todolist: listitem })
);
```

or

```
export const setTodolist = listitem => {
    return { type: "SET_TODOLIST", todolist: listitem }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after correcting my action => TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: Probably because `todolist: [...state,  action.todolist]` should be `todolist: [...state.todolist,  action.todolist]` and `store.dispatch(setTodolist({val}))` should be `store.dispatch(setTodolist(val))`

Comment: I'm a newbie in react and redux. This fixed my issues. Thanks alot :)